# CSS vertical side menu animation

Tags: jquery, css, css-animations

I am trying to animate my side nav bar similar to [this website side menu](http://demodern.com/).

I have little bit trouble with my code on which I am working. Kindly tell me if I am doing it the correct way to animate my side navbar, similar to the website which link I mentioned. If it's not like that then guide me on how I can achieve this animation effect.

CSS, jQuery one of them or both of them can use. 
My code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/arifhussain/6531foo4/). Stack Snippet below

```css
.shap {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 50%;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    background: red;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(30% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 60% 100%);
    clip-path: polygon(30% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 60% 100%);
    /*-webkit-clip-path: polygon(30% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 68% 100%);
clip-path: polygon(30% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 68% 100%);*/
}
.side {
    -webkit-animation: width .5s;
    animation: width .5s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes width {
    0% {
        -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 100% 100%);
        clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 100% 100%);
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-clip-path: polygon(99% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 60% 100%);
        clip-path: polygon(99% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 60% 100%);
    }
    55% {
        -webkit-clip-path: polygon(90% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 60% 100%);
        clip-path: polygon(90% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 60% 100%);
    }
    60% {
        -webkit-clip-path: polygon(80% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 60% 100%);
        clip-path: polygon(80% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 60% 100%);
    }
    75% {
        -webkit-clip-path: polygon(70% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 60% 100%);
        clip-path: polygon(70% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 60% 100%);
    }
    85% {
        -webkit-clip-path: polygon(60% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 60% 100%);
        clip-path: polygon(60% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 60% 100%);
    }
    90% {
        -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 60% 100%);
        clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 60% 100%);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-clip-path: polygon(30% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 60% 100%);
        clip-path: polygon(30% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 60% 100%);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="shap side side1">
    <ul class="nav-ul">
        <li class="nav-li">Nav one</li>
        <li class="nav-li">Nav one one</li>
        <li class="nav-li">Nav one</li>
        <li class="nav-li">Nav one one</li>
        <li class="nav-li">Nav one</li>
        <li class="nav-li">Nav one</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Problem is that on this website animation is smooth but my animation is not working smoothly .

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask]. This question is likely to be closed because you haven't yet met the relevant conditions for a 'why doesn't this work?' question. Also, your sample is on a website that most of us won't click on because we're in work -- you are required to explain your requirement here, not link to another site.

Answer (score 3):

**The problem**

In your specific issue, I believe you have forgotton all the [vendor prefixes required](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation) for your keyframes (you've only used the `-webkit-` prefix). adding these (and the unprefixed version) should sort out your issue for all browsers.

---

**Avoidance**

How about something like:

```js
$('.open').click(function() {
  $('.menu').toggleClass("opened");
});

$('.menu').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("opened");
});
```

```css
.open {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}
.menu {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 400px;
  background: tomato;
  top: 0;
  left: -600px;
  transition: all 0.8s;
}
.opened {
  left: -200px;
  transform: skew(-10deg);
  text-align: right;
}
.items {
  transform: skew(10deg);
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="open"></div>
<div class="menu">
  <div class="items">
    click to hide
    <br/>click to hide
    <br/>click to hide
    <br/>click to hide
    <br/>
  </div>
</div>
```

which will use *less markup* but achieve the same might be useful for you.

**Edit history**

- added extra explanation of OP's issue